# curl: (35) Recv failure: Operation timed out

Tags: terminal, homebrew

I am setting up a new catalina macbook and want to install homebrew and i keep getting this error.

```
$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
curl: (35) Recv failure: Operation timed out
zsh: command not found: -e
```

I have tried changing the DNS and tried using bin/bash instead of ruby and none of that worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote the output of the `install` script [the last time it was still present](https://github.com/Homebrew/install/blob/ed92ba68981254f3cb1935e4b0e47adaf9a14af3/install):

```
Error: The Ruby Homebrew installer is now disabled and has been rewritten in
Bash. Please migrate to the following command:
  /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Please refer to the brew.sh homepage for up-to-date [installation instructions](https://brew.sh/#install). Right now, the installation command is the very same one which was present in the script before it was deleted, namely

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```